Custom 404 Page in Multisite Environment of Sitecore JSS + Next.js
Is there a way to support customized (per site) 404 pages in a multisite environment of Sitecore JSS + Next.js? According to Sitecore, it’s not possible, but perhaps someone has figured out a workaround?
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/latest/sitecore-headless-development/the-next-js-multisite-add-on.html#limitations
Let’s assume we have two sites, A and B, within one Sitecore instance/app.
The 404 pages are structured as follows:
/sitecore/content/websites/A/Home/notfound-404
/sitecore/content/websites/B/Home/notfound-404

In our Next.js implementation, we use the standard /pages/[[...path]].tsx handler, which returns the following if the page is not found:
export const getStaticProps = async (context: StaticPropsContextWithParams) => {
  ...
  const props = await sitecorePagePropsFactory.create(context);

  if (props.notFound) {
    return {
    notFound: true,
    };
  }
  ...
};

This logic causes that current request is now handled by '/pages/404.tsx' page that has following implementation:
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  let props = {
    notFound: true,
    layoutData: null,
    componentProps: null,
    site: null,
    headLinks: [],
    dictionary: {},
    locale: 'en-gb',
  } as unknown as SitecorePageProps;

  try {
    props = await sitecorePagePropsFactory.create({
      ...context,
      params: { ...context.params, path: '/notfound-404' },
    });
  } catch (_) {
    // Handle build errors as pipeline do not have access to CD server to fetch 404 required info
  }

 

  return {
    props: {
      ...props,
      notFound: true,
    },
    revalidate: 5,
  };
};

 

However, there is an issue: Next.js only supports one custom 404 page, and we cannot pass the site name to the 404.tsx page. The site name is lost in 404.tsx (e.g., the header x-sc-rewrite is lost). This prevents us from passing the site name context to get the correct notfound-404 page for a given site (A or B). Even if we could pass it somehow (e.g., using a custom implemented request context), there would be another issue. Next.js can only have one 404 page for all sites in the cache. It will cache only one version (from the first request) since the site name is not included in the path. This can be seen by inspecting the pages generated in the cache (in the .next\server\pages\en-gb folder)—see the attached screenshot.
Is there any solution to support custom 404 pages for a multisite instance? Currently, it seems impossible as described above. Or are we missing something?

404 page issue for multisite using Sitecore JSS |
Follow the below steps to get rid of this issue.

Create _404 page under the Sitecore pages (you can not use 404 as Sitecore page name otherwise will not resolve the not found page.)

Navigate to the setting node and find the Error handling section and provide the _404 link for Page not found link (Refer below ss)



Next.js API Setup

Create an API in your Next.js project under pages/api/error/ and add a new TypeScript file.


import { GraphQLErrorPagesService } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';
import { siteResolver } from 'lib/site-resolver';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import config from 'temp/config';

import clientFactory from 'lib/graphql-client-factory';

/**
 * Gets the ErrorPages content.  We have to fetch via API to be able to get site-specific content.
 */
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const domain = req.headers.host; //will take your site host name
  let siteName;
  try {
    const site = siteResolver.getByHost(domain ?? '');
    siteName = site.name;
  } catch {
    siteName = config.sitecoreSiteName;
  }
  const errorPagesService = new GraphQLErrorPagesService({
    clientFactory,
    siteName: siteName,
    language: (req.headers.locale as string) ?? config.defaultLanguage,
    retries:
      (process.env.GRAPH_QL_SERVICE_RETRIES &&
        parseInt(process.env.GRAPH_QL_SERVICE_RETRIES, 10)) ||
      0,
  });

  try {
    const resultErrorPages = await errorPagesService.fetchErrorPages();

    res.setHeader('CDN-Cache-Control', `s-maxage=${60 * 60}, stale-while-revalidate=59`);

    // Cache settings for the browser.
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', `max-age=${60 * 60}, stale-while-revalidate=59`);

    res.status(200).json(resultErrorPages);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred while fetching error pages');
    console.error(error);

    res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occured' });
  }
}

Creating the 404.tsx Component

Create a 404.tsx file in your Next.js project and implement the following code:
 import { ErrorPages, LayoutServiceData } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';
 import Layout from 'src/Layout';
 import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
 import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';
 import NotFound from 'src/NotFound';
 import { sitecorePagePropsFactory } from 'lib/page-props-factory';

 const Custom404 = () => {
   const [layoutData, setLayoutData] = useState<LayoutServiceData>();
   const [fetchError, setFetchError] = useState(false);

   // to determine which site we're on due to middleware rewrites not executing for the 404 handler.
   useEffect(() => {
     // Only execute if we didn't get data from the default.
     // Depending on requirements, we may want to always fetch.
     if (!layoutData) {
       fetch('/api/error/content')
         .then(async (res) => {
           const data = (await res.json()) as ErrorPages | null;
           if (data?.notFoundPage.rendered) {
             // Render the not found page
             setLayoutData(data?.notFoundPage.rendered);
           } else {
             // There was no custom error page, render the fallback.
             setFetchError(true);
           }
         })
         .catch(() => {
           // There was an error, render the fallback.
           setFetchError(true);
         });
     }
     // We can't use layout data as a dependency because we are updating it
     // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
   }, []);
   // Only render the fallback if there was an error fetching the data
   if (fetchError) {
     return <NotFound />;
   }
   // If data hasn't been fetched yet, don't render anything.
   if (!layoutData) {
     return <></>;
   }

   return <Layout layoutData={layoutData} headLinks={[]} />;
 };

 export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
   if (process.env.DISABLE_SSG_FETCH || locale?.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'default') {
     return { props: {} };
   }
   // We can call layout service directly here unlike in _error since this only runs on the server
   const props = await sitecorePagePropsFactory.create({
     params: {
       path: ['_404'],
     },
     locale: locale,
   });
   return { props };
 };

 export default Custom404;



Notes for Local Testing

Update the content.ts file to include a static host name for local testing, e.g., https://abc-dev.vercel.app.
Run npm run build followed by npm run start or jss start:connected to test the setup locally.


Below are the steps to create Sitecore Content Managed 404 and 500 page error in JSS for Multisite setup.

Create 404 and 500 error pages inside site home node and update Setting item /sitecore/content/Sites/A/Settings with error page path in Sitecore.
Add GetContentManagedError api inside 'page/api' in Next JS app which will use GraphQLErrorPagesService FetchErrorPages  to get error pages from Sitecore.
Call page/api/getContentManagedError from 404 and 500 tsx file to get LayoutServiceData and return the layout data.

